# I don't understand how to write such program

Tags: c

Write a program that receives from the user a string consisting of the letters "a" and "b", which is 10 characters long (each character must be read separately). The program should also detect the signal if there is an abba sequence at the input. (For this, you cannot use arrays and sorting) I had a similar option, but it does not fit:

```
void abba();
int main()
{
abba();
return 0;
}

void abba()
 {
int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, l;
printf("Enter 10 characters");
scanf_s("%c", &a);
scanf_s("%c", &b);
scanf_s("%c", &c);
scanf_s("%c", &d);
scanf_s("%c", &e);
scanf_s("%c", &f);
scanf_s("%c", &g);
scanf_s("%c", &h);
scanf_s("%c", &k);
scanf_s("%c", &l);

if (a == 'a' && b == 'b' && c == 'b' && d == 'a')
printf("'abba' is found!");
if (b == 'a' && c == 'b' && d == 'b' && e == 'a')
printf("'abba' is found!");
if (c == 'a' && d == 'b' && e == 'b' && f == 'a')
printf("'abba' is found!");
if (d == 'a' && e == 'b' && f == 'b' && g == 'a')
printf("'abba' is foun d!");
if (e == 'a' && f == 'b' && g == 'b' && h == 'a')
printf("'abba' is found!");
if (f == 'a' && g == 'b' && h == 'b' && k == 'a')
printf("'abba' is found!");
if (g== 'a' && h == 'b' && k == 'b' && l == 'a')
printf("'abba' is found!");

}
```

Comment: Do you press the `Enter` key after each input? That will be put into the input buffer as a newline, which will be read by the next `scanf` call. That would be very clear if you used a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: As for a solution both to your problem and to the one I laid out in my previous comment, I recommend you read a *string* instead. Then use the [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) function to see if the string `"abba"` is anywhere in the input.

Comment: Use `" %c"` to read the characters.  Be appalled that you can't use an array because using an array is the only sane way to go.  Wassup with no `i` and no `j`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use arrays then you can use flags to know what you've read so far and what character you expect next to get your desired sequence. The code would be:

```
void abba(){
    int i = 0; //chars read counter
    int j = 0; //sequence counter "a" = 1, "ab" = 2, "abb" = 3, "abba" = 4
    int flag = 0; //set to 1 if j hits 4
    char a;
    printf("Enter 10 characters\n");
    while(i<10){
        scanf_s(" %c",&a);
        i++; if(i>10)break;
        if(a == 'a'){
            if(j==3){
                j++;
                flag=1;
            }
            else j=1;
        }
        else if(a == 'b' && (j==1 || j==2)){
            j++;
        }
        else{
            j=0;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1){
        printf("abba found!");
    }
    else printf("not found");
}
```

Comment: @Jad_Mrad this program doesn't work if I write abba in the end of sequence

Comment: @Aimin I just edited the code. It should work as intended now.